# How to build a scala application that was created in eclipse scala plugin FROM THE CL

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin

I have developed a scala application for the first time, but I have to deploy it with a "one-click" type script that can run and build the scala application from source WITHOUT ECLIPSE.

Since I'm completely new to scala I don't know how to tell it where all my source files are etc... to get it to build my app from the command line.  I also have 2 3rd party .jar libraries that I need to tell the scala compiler to link to...

Any documentation on this?  Or example command lines?   My project hierarchy is:

- src/packagename: contains all .scala
- bin/packagename: contains all.class files
- libs/ -> contains 2 .jar files I will need to import somehow

I'm working on debian linux

EDIT: I found this ability to export in eclipse so I created a .java file and called my main scala object from it.  Then I exported as a runnable jar.  However, when I go to run the new runnable jar "sudo java runnable.jar" it says "class not found exception: runnable.jar"

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki which is the common way to build a Scala project. Run through the tutorial in the wiki to learn how you should organise your directory structure, so that everything may run fine.

If you want to combine it with eclipse, checkout this plugin: https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse